# Insert text in a website and scrape generated request

Tags: python, web-scraping

I will try to explain my problem as detailed as possible. I don't even know the correct terminologies for this. Therefore, I couldn't search exactly for my problem.
I want to use this [website](https://www.howmanysyllables.com/syllable_counter/) to count syllables of a sentence and scrape the generated number of syllables per sentence into a .txt file using and libraries of Python. So here is what I want to do step by step:

1- Open this URL:
https://www.howmanysyllables.com/syllable_counter/

2- Enter some sentences inside the syllables counter field.

3- Click on the "Count Syllables" button under the field.

4- Scrape the numbers generated to left.

I can do step 4 by scraping the numbers form the website. My struggle is with steps 2 and 3. I was able to use a defined function to count syllables within the code, but the results do not match those in the website.

I hope that I have explained the problem as clearly as possible.

Comment: Can you what you have tried so far ?

Comment: have you considered  [robotframework](https://robotframework.org/) to perform this task?

Comment: if page use JavaScript then you may need tools like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript. If page doesn't use JavaScript then you can use `requests` or `urllib` to get HTML from server and send data to server, `lxml` or `Beautifulsoup` to search in HTML. And it works faster then Selenium  because it doesn't use browser but for beginner may need more time to write it.

Comment: @Sushanth I didn't write any code because I don't know where to start

Comment: @bigbear3001 I am not used to working with this framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will send `sentence` as parameter in POST request to the page and gets the results in text form:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sentence = 'I will try to explain my problem as detailed as possible.'

url = 'https://www.howmanysyllables.com/syllable_counter/'
soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser' )

payload = {}
for i in soup.select('form[action="/syllable_counter/"] input[value]'):
    payload[i['name']] = i['value']
payload['UQ_txt'] = sentence

soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.post(url, data=payload).text, 'html.parser' )
for a in soup.select('#foot_M .Answer_Red'):
    print('{}{}'.format(a.text, a.find_next_sibling(text=True)))
```

Prints:

```
11 words
16 syllables
57 characters
```

---

EDIT: To send multiple lines, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sentences = [
    'This is line one.'
    'This is line two.'
    'This is line three.'
]

url = 'https://www.howmanysyllables.com/syllable_counter/'
soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser' )

payload = {}
for i in soup.select('form[action="/syllable_counter/"] input[value]'):
    payload[i['name']] = i['value']
payload['UQ_txt'] = '\n'.join(sentences)

soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.post(url, data=payload).text, 'html.parser' )
for a in soup.select('#foot_M .Answer_Red'):
    print('{}{}'.format(a.text, a.find_next_sibling(text=True)))
```

Prints:

```
12 words
12 syllables
53 characters
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!
Thank you very much!
I only need syllables, and therefore I edited the code a bit to return only this value.

Comment: how could I use this code to send multiple lines on the website? The website accepts multiple lines and can return multiple values for each with one request. I could use a for loop to send each line to the website and get the result for each line,  but this is a slower process.

Comment: This is amazing. Cheers to you!

Answer (score 1):

Here example with [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

It may need driver to control web browser [Firefox](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/) or [Chrome](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

Every line of code described in comments in code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
  
url = 'https://www.howmanysyllables.com/syllable_counter/'

# open browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# load page
driver.get(url)

# find field 
item = driver.find_element_by_id('syl_input')

# put text
item.send_keys('Hello World')

# find button 
item = driver.find_element_by_id('button_submit')

# click button
item.click()

# find all red numbers 
all_answers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Answer_Red')
#for answer in all_answers:
#    print(answer.text)

# display numbers
print('words:', all_answers[0].text)
print('syllables:', all_answers[1].text)
print('characters:', all_answers[2].text)
```

---

**BTW:** sometimes it is easier to write it with `Selenium` but version with `requests` (in other answer) should work faster.

Comment: A very clean answer indeed. Although, I hated the fact that this code must open the browser every time it runs. I am willing to create a for loop to run the code for multiple sentences.

Comment: you can run loop after opening browser and you will have one browser all time. And browsers have option `--headless` to run without displaying window so you don't have to see this window and it can run faster - but still version with `requests` will be run fater :)

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I will surely implement it in future projects.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy! you can use the powerful and easy-to-use python library named 'selenium' to interact with webpages in python.

**1-Installing libraries:**
to install tools, you just need to open a windows command prompt and type:

```
pip install selenium
pip instal chromedriver-py==[your Chrome version]
```

for example, if your chrome version is 108.0.5359.125, you just need to type this (you can access your chrome version from this Chrome: setting->about):

```
pip install chromedriver-py==108.*
```

and that's it!

**2-Opening chrome window by python**

Then, open a new code and type this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from chromewebdriver_py import binary_path
from time import sleep
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(binary_path)
driver.maximize()
```

This code opens a chrome window and maximizes it! Be aware to type Exactly "Chrome" capitalized the first letter. if you are confused about that, it's completely natural! You just need to copy the first lines of your code in the first days of training!

**3-Navigate your browser to the desired URL!**

```
URL = "https://www.howmanysyllables.com/syllable_counter/"
driver.get(URL)
```

BOOM! You can enjoy that your driver goes automatically to your desired link!

**4-Finding address of your desired element in the webpage**

It is very easy but sometimes tricky! As you may know, every element in a webpage can be accessed by its address. There are several methods to address the element but the most famous one is the CSS selector. It's not hard and you can learn it by googling but chrome has made it even easier!
You just need to right-click on your desired element on the page and click on "Inspect". For example, in your problem, if you did this on the text box, this window would appear to you(on the right side):
[image]

and then you need to right-click on the element in this new window and then copy->copy selector as shown below. Then you have all you want!
[image]

**5-Interacting with the element**
Here, we have the path of the element by coping from chrome. here we need to find this element in python and then interact with it! For this purpose:

```
path = "Enter the CSS selector that you copied"
elem = driver.find_element('css selector', path)

elem.clear() # to clear the text box
elem.send_keys("Your desired number")
```

And you did it! Enjoy automatically inputting a number by Python! Be aware to type Exactly 'css selector' with a lower letter to not get any errors!:-)

**6-clicking on button**
This is the same as the previous section! You  just need to copy the selector of this button(Count to Syllables button) by Righ-click and:

```
path = "Enter the CSS selector that you copied"
elem = driver.find_element('css selector', path)
elem.click()
sleep(0.5) # waiting a little time to ensure that the calculation has been completed
```

**7- Extracting result from output textbox**
This is also very similar to the last step! but here, you have three result(words, syllables and characters). if we right-click on this output box, we will see this:
[image]

As you see, if we move our mouse in this inspect window, we would see that our desired elements are 'span' elements!:
[image]
if we copy selector one of these 'span' elements, the copied CSS selector would be:

```
#foot_M > span:nth-child(1)
```

It's very beautiful! ':nth-child(1)' means the first element that matches this CSS selector, so if we remove this part as below:

```
#foot_M > span
```

we would have a CSS selector that match all the 'spans'! We can check this address in Chrome! In 'inspect' window, press (Cntrl+f) and then copy this CSS selector as below! Chrome will show you all the elements matching this address!
[image]

Pay attention that chrome has found 3 items that match this address. Excellent! by this method, you can check your CSS selector in chrome itself and you don't have to check it in python which consumes more time and effort! I found this method by experiment! I wish someone has told me it sooner!

So, we have all we need, but here, we need to type driver.find_elements in the plural form to find all of the elements!

```
path = "#foot_M > span"
elems = driver.find_elements('css selector', path)
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
```

Congratulation! You have done it! the last step is to put this code in a 'for' loop and then sit and drink your tea while python does this repetitive work for you!