# How to insert number into website and receive output it generates

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a list of catalan numbers. Python calculator breaks with huge numbers. How could I make a for loop and put the n'th number into this website http://www.kourbatov.com/math/calculators/catalannumberscalculator.htm
click the calculate button, and save the resulting number in an array?
I hope you can help!

[Insert text in a website and scrape generated request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62788496/insert-text-in-a-website-and-scrape-generated-request)
I saw this post but it didnt help me. I'm not that good at programming to understand how to make it apply to this website.

Comment: It looks like the calculation is done in javascript, which means you will need to have Python simulate a browser and interact with the website. You can do this with something like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). However, if you view the source of that website, all of the math (including the calculations with big integers) is available. It is probably better to just re-implement that code in Python.

Comment: Where can you see the calculation? I couldnt find it sorry. I really just need code to calculate very large catalan numbers...

Comment: Right click anywhere on the page and click view source. The JS is embedded there.

Comment: The bistro.js thing?

Comment: never mind the catalcalculator lol?

Comment: Both of them are used for the calc. Btw, why does your code not work for large numbers? I just wrote a simple one-liner and it works for `n = 25000` which is the maximum for the site you linked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250506/discussion-between-akilan-manivannan-and-goob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy! you can use the powerful and easy-to-use python library named 'selenium' to interact with webpages in python.

**1-Installing libraries:**
to install tools, you just need to open a windows command prompt and type:

```
pip install selenium
pip instal chromedriver-py==[your Chrome version]
```

for example, if your chrome version is 108.0.5359.125, you just need to type this (you can access your chrome's version from this Chrome: setting->about):

```
pip install chromedriver-py==108.*
```

and that's it!

**2-Opening chrome window by python**

Then, open a new code and type this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from chromewebdriver_py import binary_path
from time import sleep
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(binary_path)
driver.maximize()
```

This code opens a chrome window and maximizes it! Be aware to type Exactly "Chrome" capitalized the first letter. if you are confused about that, it's completely natural! You just need to copy the first lines of your code in the first days of training!

**3-Navigate your browser to the desired URL!**

```
URL = "http://www.kourbatov.com/math/calculators/catalannumberscalculator.htm"
driver.get(URL)
```

BOOM! You can enjoy that your driver goes automatically to your desired link!

**4-Finding address of your desired element in the webpage**

It is very easy but sometimes tricky! As you may know, every element in a webpage can be accessed by its address. There are several methods to address the element but the most famous one is the CSS selector. It's not hard and you can learn it by googling but chrome has made it even easier!
You just need to right-click on your desired element on the page and click on "Inspect". For example, in your problem, if you did this on the text box, this window would appear to you:
[image]

and then you just need to right-click on the element in this new window and then copy->copy selector as shown below. Then you have all you want!
[image]

---

**5-Interacting with the element**
Here, we have the path of the element by coping from chrome. here we need to find this element in python and then interact with it! For this purpose:

```
path = "Enter the CSS selector that you copied"
elem = driver.find_element('css selector', path)

elem.clear() # to clear the text box
elem.send_keys("Your desired number")
```

And you did it! Enjoy automatically inputting a number by Python! Be aware to type Exactly 'css selector' with a lower letter to not get any errors!:-)

**6-clicking on Calculate button**
This is the same as the previous section! You  just need to copy the selector of this button by Righ-click and:

```
path = "Enter the CSS selector that you copied"
elem = driver.find_element('css selector', path)
elem.click()
sleep(0.5) # waiting a little time to ensure that the calculation has been completed
```

**7- Extracting result from output textbox**
This is also very similar to the last step! You need to copy the CSS selector of the output textbox by Chrome and:

```
path = "Enter the CSS selector that you copied"
elem = driver.find_element('css selector', path)
result = elem.txt
```

Congratulation! You have done it! the last step is to put this code in a 'for' loop and then sit and drink your tea while python does this repetitive work for you!