# how to get xpath or smth other in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I use it to find the element containing the word "Python Tutorial"`

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver =  webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://pythonbasics.org/")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//*[text()='Python Tutorial]"))
```

how to get xpath address from it
like this "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/main/div[3]/div[1]/div"
I used python to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select element using XPATH syntax on Selenium for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035186/how-to-select-element-using-xpath-syntax-on-selenium-for-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extract it by right-clicking on the object you want and selecting inspect. The browser will show it to you automatically. You can find a detailed explanation on this page:

[How to insert number into website and receive output it generates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74839763/how-to-insert-number-into-website-and-receive-output-it-generates/74840071#74840071)

Here is another example:

[Insert text in a website and scrape generated request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62788496/insert-text-in-a-website-and-scrape-generated-request/74872008#74872008)

I recommend using “css selector” instead of xpath. css selector is easier to understand! If you have any questions, I am happy to help!

Comment: i want to click on an element containing any word but it can change position xpath
it's like this:
<img data-v-d960c7a2="" src="../../assets/images/icons-new/success.svg" class="mr-2 icons-new" style="width: 19px;">
"Click"
I don't know how to find exactly this element
when i find that element by above and .click()
it has no response

Comment: and some elements also have the same id